# PHP Looping through large data array to create another one

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a very huge multidimensional array and I want to create another one, merging all the elements with the same `mapping_id` into one array. I'm trying with a `foreach` but It takes too long, is there any other solution? This is what I have:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($objects as $obj) {
    $newArray[$obj['mapping_id']][] = $obj;
}
```

`$objects` is a multidimensional array that contains the keys `mapping_id` and other ones.

Comment: Can i see the first index of your datas?

Answer (score 2):

Use array_chunk. From PHP net manual:
Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may contain less than size elements.
try this:

```
$newArray = [];
$rows = array_chunk($objects, 100);

foreach ($rows as $obj) {
    $newArray[$obj['mapping_id']][] = $obj;
}
```

Hope this help.